# TF/Keras: ModelCheckpoint "period" and "save_best_only"

Tags: tensorflow, keras

If I use Keras callback `ModelCheckpoint`, and I put `save_best_only = True` and `period=3`, how will the model be saved? After 3 period it saves the best result from that 3 period, or it just saves the best one of all epochs?
Piece of code that I used:

```py
mcp = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("my_model.h5", monitor="val_accuracy",
                        save_best_only=True, period=3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, according to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), `period` argument is deprecated in favor of `save_freq` argument (which if assigned to an `int`, it would consider number of seen batches and not the epochs). But for backwards compatibility, the `period` argument is still working.

But to find out the answer to your question, we need to inspect the source code for `ModelCheckpoint` callback. Actually, the best value of monitored metric seen so far [is updated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1210) only [if `period` epochs has passed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1193-L1194) (since the last checkpoint). And also. since the best metric value seen so far [is compared](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1205) with the monitored metric value of only current epoch, therefore we can conclude that only the best performing model in epochs `period`, `2*period`, `3*period`, etc. are compared and saved, and the performance of the model between those epochs **is ignored**.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the source code to find the answer. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `period=3` will attempt to save a model every 3 batches. If you want it to save at the end of every epoch, set `period='epoch'`.
If `save_best_only=True` it will check to see if the validation accuracy is higher this time than last time and only save that model. If the validation accuracy is not this high, it will not save the model.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint#arguments_1